# Pandas: print without dtype information

Tags: python, pandas

I have `predictions.iloc[5]`:

```
(predictions.iloc[5])
Out[102]: 
0    569.366922
Name: 5, dtype: float64
```

I also have `mape`

```
mape
Out[103]: 3.1396327381728257
```

I'm combining the two variables into `forecast`

```
forecast = ((predictions.iloc[5]), mape)
```

I'm trying to print without the `Name: 5, dtype: float64` detail

but when I try:

```
print(forecast.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_string'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `.values[0]` with `iloc`:

```
forecast = ((predictions.iloc[5].values[0]), mape)
```

Or use unpacking by adding `*` before `predictions.iloc[0]`:

```
forecast = (*predictions.iloc[0], mape)
```

Then, you can simply print by:

```
print(*forecast, sep=' ')
```

Comment: thanks, using forecast = ((predictions.iloc[5].values[0]), mape) and then using print(forecast.to_string(index=False, header=False)) returns AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_string'

Comment: I think then, you can simply use `print(*forecast, sep=' ')` without use of  `to_string`